# Regex not operator

Tags: regex, string, operators

Is there an NOT operator in Regexes?
Like in that string : `"(2001) (asdf) (dasd1123_asd 21.01.2011 zqge)(dzqge) name (20019)"`

I want to delete all `\([0-9a-zA-z _\.\-:]*\)` but not the one where it is a year: `(2001)`.

So what the regex should return must be: `(2001) name`.

NOTE: something like `\((?![\d]){4}[0-9a-zA-z _\.\-:]*\)` does not work for me (the `(20019)` somehow also matches...)

Comment: There is a String like above and I want to regex it up, that the result of the regex is: `(2001) name`.

Answer (score 201, accepted):

No, there's no direct not operator. At least not the way you hope for.

You can use a zero-width negative lookahead, however:

```
\((?!2001)[0-9a-zA-z _\.\-:]*\)
```

The `(?!...)` part means "only match if the text *following* (hence: lookahead) this *doesn't* (hence: negative) match this. But it doesn't actually *consume* the characters it matches (hence: zero-width).

There are actually 4 combinations of [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) with 2 axes:

- lookbehind / lookahead : specifies if the characters *before* or *after* the point are considered
- positive / negative : specifies if the characters *must* match or *must not* match.

Comment: Thank you the ?! is what I was suggesting too, but anyway if I use `\((?![\d]{4})[0-9a-zA-z _\.\-:]+\)` there is still `(20019)` in it

Comment: In the edit of your question you put the `{4}` *outside* the lookahead and in this comment you put it *inside*: which one did you try? Also: if you want `(20019)` to match, then you must add the `\)` *inside* your lookahead: `\((?![\d]{4}\))[0-9a-zA-z _\.\-:]+\)`

Comment: With the regex above in your comment, it works. But I don't understand that... I don't get why you escape the following part ``\((?![\d]{4} -->\)<--)[0-9a-zA-z _\.\-:]+\)`` Then there is a bracket not closed, isn't it?

Comment: I escape the closing parenthesis `)` because I want to match the **literal** character `)` (just as you do at the very beginning and the very end of your regex!). Then *after* I matched that, I end the lookahead by using an unescaped `)`.

Comment: Got it. I was a little bit confused by all that characters. Thank you.

Comment: Pardon the edit. Already handled in comments, so I reverted it.

Comment: if you don't need to test for anything else afterwards then the pure '(?!...)' sequence works quite well.

Answer (score 441):

Not quite, although generally you can usually use some workaround on one of the forms

- `[^abc]`, which is character by character not `a` or `b` or `c`,
- or negative lookahead: `a(?!b)`, which is `a` not followed by `b`
- or negative lookbehind: `(?<!a)b`, which is `b` not preceeded by `a`

Comment: Yep, I think negative look-behind is (?<!a)b -- reference: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: But `[^abc]` should mean not `a` or `b` or `c`, not "not the string `abc`".

Comment: Thanks. `%[^sdf]` or `%(?!(s|d|f))` equals to "contains %", but not "%s", "%d" or "%f".

Comment: negative look(ahead|behind) also allows for easy negation of multiple letters, e.g. `you(?!tube)` or `(?<!docker)hub`

Comment: `a(?!b)` (a not followed by b) is brillant. Best answer. 

Answer (score 1):

You could capture the `(2001)` part and replace the rest with nothing.

```
public static string extractYearString(string input) {
    return input.replaceAll(".*\(([0-9]{4})\).*", "$1");
}

var subject = "(2001) (asdf) (dasd1123_asd 21.01.2011 zqge)(dzqge) name (20019)";
var result = extractYearString(subject);
System.out.println(result); // <-- "2001"
```

`.*\(([0-9]{4})\).*` means

- `.*` match anything
- `\(` match a `(` character
- `(` begin capture
- `[0-9]{4}` any single digit four times
- `)` end capture
- `\)` match a `)` character
- `.*` anything (rest of string)

Comment: Use `.replace()` with a global regex flag, since `.replaceAll()` is not supported by a lot of browsers and also node.

Comment: @lorikku java != javascript

Comment: @zyexal Oh oops! I didn't realise it was java haha, my bad!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative:

```
(\(\d{4}\))((?:\s*\([0-9a-zA-z _\.\-:]*\))*)([^()]*)(( ?\([0-9a-zA-z _\.\-:]*\))*)
```

Repetitive patterns are embedded in a single group with this construction, where the inner group is not a capturing one: `((:?pattern)*)`, which enable to have control on the group numbers of interrest.

Then you get what you want with: `\1\3`