# MySQL REGEX WHERE clause for zip code

Tags: mysql, regex, where-clause

I have a database that I am trying to clean out. They have 70k entries with some bad values in the zip code column. I want to go through and delete the rows that do not have a valid 5 or 9 digit zip code. This the current statement I have:

```
SELECT * FROM `sample_requests` WHERE `request_zip` RegExp '^\d{5}$)|(^\d{5}-\d{4}$)'
```

I am not very familiar with regular expressions, but I know enough. Also this particular regex is used on the form now, so that it will not submit without a valid zip code so I know it works. I just can't get the MySQL portion to work.

Comment: You're missing an opening parenthesis:  `'(^\d{5}$)|(^\d{5}-\d{4}$)'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `DELETE` instead of `SELECT`. Before you do this, you might want to create a duplicate 'sample_requests' table in case you make a mistake.

here's the command you're interested in (deleting the duplicate table rows first so you know it works):

```
DELETE FROM sample_requests_duplicate 
WHERE request_zip NOT RegExp '(^\d{5}$)|(^\d{5}-\d{4}$)'
```

Comment: Right. I have just been trying to get the RegExp portion to work and figured SELECT was a little safer than DELETE. :)  Will the code that you gave me delete the good ones though? How do you say "WHERE !=" with regular expressions?

Comment: check my new answer, it has the `NOT` syntax (`=` or `!=` won't work), if that doesn't work, isn't there a `!` in Regex? I'm not the best at that so i don't know

Comment: Thank you. You answered my question. The NOT doesn't seem to work, so I will have to try and figure out how the Regex ! operator works.

Comment: @JEFFB great, glad to help, see the answer at the very bottom of this SO page for more on `!`/`NOT` operator in Regex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317043/regex-not-operator