# Is it possible to create a regex that will find strings that DO NOT match a pattern?

Tags: java, regex

I have this situation where I need to pull a bunch of zipfiles from a server using a prebuilt SFTP client.  I only want the ones that do not have `_PROCESSED` in their filename.  For example, `covers.zip` would be ok but `covers_PROCESSED.zip` would not.  I have a current working solution for this where I run `lsFiles()`, which returns all the filenames in the directory and then run a function that filters them based on whether they have that keyword in their filename.  They are then pulled from the server.

However, in the sftp client I'm using, there is also this function: `lsFiles(String pattern)`, which returns anything that matches the pattern. I want to use this function to get only the filenames I want, since this would both shorten and optimize my code a bit.  The problem is, I don't know how to make a regex that will only match things if they DO NOT have the given pattern (or if this is even possible). Can someone tell me if this is possible, and if so, provide an example of how to do this?

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317043/regex-not-operator)

Comment: Is the `_PROCESSED` string always in a known location in the string?

Comment: Also related with excellent info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word

Comment: @Jim, that's not really a reliable way to do it. Your expression would filter out `covers_PROC.zip` too

Comment: @Floris Yes, `_PROCESSED` will always be right before `.zip` in the filename

Comment: I am searching online for a sftp client with a `lsFiles()` function - the ones I found admit simple filters (like `*.zip`) but not true `regex`. Can you tell us what sftp client you are using?

Comment: It's one that the company that I'm working for built, but its based on the JCraft 3rd party API

Comment: @Jim no, square brackets denote a character class, so your suggestion will match any _single character_ that is not D, E, C, S, O, R, P or underscore.

Comment: Deleted erroneous suggestion of [^_PROCESSED]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure thing, boss

```
/(?!_PROCESSED)/
```

This is a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and it's supported in almost all regexp flavours

Comment: Are the slashes meant to be part of the regex? It's unclear to me at the moment *exactly* what the OP would do.

Comment: No need to be nervous - but it would be good to show how this would be used *in the Java context*. Do you mean just `lsFiles("(?!_PROCESSED)")` or something else? (I've been trying to test this using `Pattern.matcher`, and I can't get it to do what I want...)

Comment: This won't currently work, as you need the brackets round `?!_PROCESSED` to turn it into negative lookahead... but *just* adding the brackets doesn't work either. There's more required, but I'm not sure what yet.

Comment: While your example may or may not work, all i need is a regex string to match the files that do not have the `_PROCESSED` in their name.  The regex you initially put up is not working for me. I already have a function that filters out the filenames I don't want, now I want to change it so that I never need to do that, it just initially pulls the right filenames.

Answer (score 0):

If your client filters with true regex, then

```
lsFiles("(?!_PROCESSED)\.zip")
```

should return all `zip` files that were not processed. But usually file filters just allow simple wildcard substitution (of the `*.zip` variety), so I would be surprised if this actually worked. If it doesn't, then taking a listing of all `.zip` files and filtering them is the right approach - but you already knew that.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude a specific substring using this kind of pattern:

```
^(?>[^_]++|_(?!PROCESSED))+$
```

As you can see it use an alternation between `[^_]++` *(all that is not a `_`)* and `_(?!PROCESSED)` *(`_` not followed by `PROCESSED`)*.

The interest of this kind of pattern is that you avoid to check character by character if there is not `_PROCESSED` somewhere, but only when you meet the first character of the string you want to exclude. Thus, the test number is considerably reduced.

The function suggested by naomik seems to be appropriate for what you are trying to do:

```
listFilesMatching(new File("/some/path", "^(?>[^_]++|_(?!PROCESSED))+$");
```