# Regex NOT Operation

Tags: java, html, regex, regex-negation

I have condition where I have to select anything which is not part of span tag.

Input -

```
the <span class='ptc-highlightedSearchResult'>PISTON</span> has their <span class='ptc-highlightedSearchResult'>ROD</span> ring
```

regex which selects `<span>` tag and it's content -

```
(<span[^>]+class\s*=\s*("|')ptc-highlightedSearchResult\2[^>]*>)[^<]*(</span>)
```

I'm able to select whatever comes in span and their content but not otherwise. Any help on NOT operation will be appreciated.

Comment: Why not use a library that already handles XML or HTML?  Regular expressions are not best suited for markup like this, as you can find throughout SO.

Comment: @BLaZuRE - I can't use them, I have some limitations about edit and have to do it with regex only. Pls pass on your suggestions.

Comment: I'm assuming then that http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/package-summary.html won't help you?  Try this for more on the not operator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317043/regex-not-operator

Comment: @DevendraW You can use this regex in a replace to remove all the span and you'll be left of what's outside.

Comment: @Jerry - Sorry but I can't remove the content of span and span either. I just want to select remaining text and want to highlight them as user enters his inputs. so <span> tags will keep adding on page. pls suggest regex to avoid them and their contents and select other string part.

Comment: @DevendraW And you want to 'unselect' only the parts inside span tags and no other tags? You could have something like [this](http://regex101.com/r/aI0iE0), but this avoids other tags as well.

Comment: You could use `negative lookaround` here. Replace `<span` with `<(?!span)` and `</span>` with `</(?!span)`. That should select all tags but spans. But it won't be able to handle nested tags.

Comment: @Jerry Your suggestions is close but it selects the content/string between <span></span> as well. See in link you pasted, in result, Piston and ROD should not be selected and 'the' 'has their' 'ring' should be selected. Pls suggest with this correction. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
((?:(?![^<>]*(?:>))[^<](?![^<>]*</))+)
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/lS6vU0)

It will match any text not inside or between opening and closing tags. There's a breakdown of the regex in the demo.