# RegEx match text wrap from close open tag

Tags: php, regex

follow string must be match

```
das is<C strike ><c1>t ein text </c1></C><C u ><c1>der </c1></C><C b u ><c1>hier </c1></C>im <C i u ><c1>editor </c1></C><u></u>steht
```

my regex don't work

```
>(.*?)<
```

thats match all text between tags, 
but i need only follow result, for my it's only the text interested was no warp from any TAG (for this sample like )

```
match[0] ------> das is
match[1] ------> im 
match[2] ------> steht
```

but i become this:

```
match[0] ------> das is
match[1] ------> t ein text 
match[2] ------> der 
match[3] ------> hier 
match[4] ------> im 
match[5] ------> editor 
match[6] ------> steht
```

Comment: Sorry, but I can't imagine anyone would understand what you are trying to achieve. Please ask a colleague to form proper English sentences so that we can get an idea of what you are talking about.
Btw, you might want to grab some kind of learning-english-book, since even a german programmer should be able to get the basics of the english language ;-) Nur ein kleiner Tipp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggested this regex in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19109356/1578604), I guess this however fits your case perfectly:

```
(?:(?![^<>]*(?:>))[^<])+
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/zS1rX8)

Use `preg_match_all` by the way.

EDIT: You can try this:

```
([^<>]+)(<[^>]+>(?:[^<>]*|(?2))</[^>]+>)*
```

[viper-7 demo](http://viper-7.com/lAKquI)

Or another regex:

```
(?:(?![^<>]*(?:>))[^<](?![^<>]*</))+
```

Comment: nearly :)

your regex match all text between TAGs, but i need only the text which no wrap from tag's, specifically in this case are this follow strings

    match[0] ------> das is
    match[1] ------> im 
    match[2] ------> steht

Comment: yes it's right... with this regex i can better to wrap the matched strings

Comment: @ jerry it's possible to write you a e-mail because i have a "sensitive sourcecode" (less 5 lines - I do not want to publish the source code)  ...

Topic is: regex

Comment: @ jerry no, its works all fine :)
but i have a source-code  ... I would like that (only) you to recheck code. (less 5 lines) (I do not publish this on the internet ;)

Comment: @Nico Well, I guess you can send me an email. This should be visible in my StackOverflow profile I think.

Comment: ok, i try to write you a messeag over your deviantart website