# regex return a match if NO match found

Tags: regex

I have a file naming pattern such as

*this is a 9876 file name* **.1234.ext**

OR

*thisisa9876filename* **.4321.ext**

I can return a match easily enough for .1234.ext by using

```
/(\.\d{4}\.ext)$/
```

What I want to do is find a match if it is not that format. e.g.

*thisisa9876filename.123.ext*

OR

*this is a 9876 file name.txe*

So effectively if it doesn't match that pattern I want to return a match.

I can't seem to work out any solution to this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not just invert the output of the current regex match?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7317116/3458162

Comment: Maybe try a negative look behind from the end of the the string

Comment: what is the format of your input ? a number of lines ? sentences ?

Comment: What is your environment/flavor? Is is it grep, perl, ...? What tool do you use to apply the regex? How do you apply the regex?

Comment: What is the match you want to return? The whole line?

Answer (score 0):

To pick up on the solution suggested by @Nick, and assuming that you work with, or have access to, R, the solution could be this:
If this is (like) your data:

```
data <- c("thisisa9876filename .4321.ext", "thisisa9876filename.123.ext", 
          "this is a 9876 file name.txe", "this is a 9876 file name .1234.ext")
```

then you can use `grep`and its `invert = T` argument to match anything the pattern does not match:

```
grep("\\d{4}\\.ext$", data, value = T, invert = T)
[1] "thisisa9876filename.123.ext"  "this is a 9876 file name.txe"
```

Answer (score 0):

If a negative lookahead `(?!` is supported, you could assert that the string does not end with your pattern:

```
^(?!.*\.\d{4}\.ext$).+$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not

  - `.*\.\d{4}\.ext$` Match a dot and 4 digits followed by `.ext` at the end of the string
- `)` Close lookahead
- `.+` Match any char except a newline 1+ times
- `$` End of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DvnYwK/1)

Comment: Thats terrific the forth bird.  Thank you. If you had the time to explain the logic that would be really helpful thank you.

Comment: @Kent I have added an explanation of the different parts of the pattern.

Comment: awsome thank you.  That makes sense now.  It appears my problem was not matching all characters after the negative lookahead.  So effectively it is saying match all characters if the negative lookahead is true.  Thanks so much @the forth bird