# How to split on / but not on // in R?

Tags: r, regex, split

Say i have this string:

```
str <- "a//b/c"
```

**Desired Output:**

```
c("a//b", "c").
```

So i want to split on /, but not on //.

**What i tried:**

Following https://stackoverflow.com/a/7317087/8538074 i tried:

```
  strsplit(split = "[[]^//[]]|/", x = "a//b/c", perl = TRUE)
```

(For non R-user: One Needs to escape Special characters in R, so "[" becomes "[[]", not sure this is common in all other languages.)

Answer (score 5):

You may use

```
strsplit("a//b/c", "(?<!/)/(?!/)", perl=TRUE)
```

See the [R demo online](https://rextester.com/SSO80417) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/frG4kZ/1).

The `(?<!/)/(?!/)` pattern means:

- `(?<!/)` -  a location that is not immediately preceded with `/`
- `/` - a `/` char
- `(?!/)` -  a location that is not immediately followed with `/`

Answer (score 2):

We can also `SKIP` the pattern and match otherss

```
strsplit(str, "//(*SKIP)(*F)|/", perl = TRUE)[[1]]
#[1] "a//b" "c"
```