# match all urls except urls with "static" word

Tags: java, regex

I have this URL matching

```
get("/portal/*", (req, res) -> { Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<>();
                return new VelocityTemplateEngine().render(
                        new ModelAndView(model, "../../portal/index.html")
                );
            });
```

All URLs like:

```
/portal/
/portal/orders
/portal/orders/123
/portal/foo/bar
```

Should return index.html. It works but I need to skip static resources. And I don't know how to do it. Something like this:

"/portal/{not word static}/*" - in other words, this URL should be not handled: `/portal/static/css/main.css`

Comment: You can use something like this: `/portal/(?!static).*`, see also: [Regex not operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317043/regex-not-operator)

Comment: Also note that `get("/portal/*", ..)` is probably not a regex, so you'd need to find a way to configure the path match to use regex

Comment: Assuming you're using Spark Framework, the `get` method doesn't use regular expressions. You are asking the wrong question.

Comment: @k314159 I agree. If you know this framework, could you help me with another question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66851385/how-can-i-return-index-html-from-webapp-folder-instead-of-resources-folder-in

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
\/portal\/(?!static\/).*
```

You can try it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/LdDIFo/1).