# Get text inside brackets along with splitting delimiters in regex java?

Tags: java, regex, split, delimiter

I have a multiline string which is delimited by a set of different delimiters,

```
A Z DelimiterB B X DelimiterA (C DelimiterA D) DelimiterB (E DelimiterA F) DelimiterB G DelimiterA H
```

I need to split that string by delimiters, but if some words are inside brackets then extract the bracket as a single word even if it contains a delimiter. I need them to be extract as follows,

```
A Z
DelimiterB
B X
DelimiterA
(C DelimiterA D) (extract with brackets)
DelimiterB
(E DelimiterA F)
DelimiterB
G
DelimiterA
H
```

Currently I am using this expression to split by delimiters,

```
(((?<=DelimiterA)|(?=DelimiterA))|((?<=DelimiterB)|(?=DelimiterB)))
```

I tried the following but it is not working. So how can I make this to work?

```
((?=\()|(?<=\))|(((?<=DelimiterA)|(?=DelimiterA))|((?<=DelimiterB)|(?=DelimiterB))))
```

Java Code,

```
String txt = "A DelimiterB B DelimiterA (C DelimiterA D) DelimiterB (E DelimiterA F) DelimiterB G DelimiterA H";
String[] texts = txt.split("((?=\()|(?<=\))|(((?<=DelimiterA)|(?=DelimiterA))|((?<=DelimiterB)|(?=DelimiterB))))");

for (String word : texts) {
    System.out.println(word);
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you use `split` as you need the "delimiter" in your result. From what given, below should do the job.
`Scanner scanner = new Scanner(txt);scanner.findAll("\\w+|\\(\\w+ \\w+ \\w+\\)").map(matchResult -> matchResult.group()).forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: I tried it. But the texts between delimiters may contains 2 words like this. `A Z DelimiterB B X DelimiterA (C DelimiterA D)`. So I need to get `A Z` as one word and `B X` as one word and then `(C DelimiterA D)` like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### IMO, Matching is easier than Splitting

Since the "delimiter" is also needed, I suggest to match the pattern we need instead. Base on the example given, we have below patterns to capture.

1. `(C DelimiterA D)` - Bracket contain a word, delimiter and a word
   which is `"\\(\\w+ (DelimiterA|DelimiterB) \\w+\\)"`
2. `DelimiterB` - Whole Delimiter.
   which is `"(DelimiterA|DelimiterB)"`.
3. `B`, `B X` - One or multiple words which are not delimiter.
   How to check the word is not delimiter?
   We can check the " " in between is not followed/preceded by delimiter([check Regex not operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317043/regex-not-operator)), which is `"\\w+((?<!(DelimiterA|DelimiterB))\\s(?!(DelimiterA|DelimiterB))\\w+)*"`.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SplitWithCustomDelimiter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String txt = "A Z DelimiterB B X DelimiterA (C DelimiterA D) DelimiterB (E DelimiterA F) DelimiterB G DelimiterA H";
        // scanner can accept different source
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(txt);
        scanner.findAll(
                "\\(\\w+ (DelimiterA|DelimiterB) \\w+\\)" +
                "|(DelimiterA|DelimiterB)" +
                "|\\w+((?<!(DelimiterA|DelimiterB))\\s(?!(DelimiterA|DelimiterB))\\w+)*"
                )
                .map(matchResult -> matchResult.group()).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and appreciate the detailed explanation. But one more thing, can I match the word with special characters also? But it is optional. If the special characters found still match it?

Comment: @AbrahamArnold Replace those `\\w` to `[a-zA-Z0-9!+#]`, add any special character you need inside `[]` should do the job.

Comment: It did the job. Thank you very much again.